# Oracle case when, else, then error - missing keyword

Tags: oracle, case

The table I'm working with has these weird coded times, I'm trying to format them. The error I'm getting is "Missing Keyword". TRANS_NUMBER is a string of numbers that I need reformat.

```
 CASE POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER
                      WHEN '' THEN '' 
                      WHEN NULL THEN '' 
                      WHEN SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,10,1) =':' THEN CONCAT('0', SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,9,1)) 
                      ELSE SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,9,2) 
                      END AS "POSTED_HOUR",

                CASE POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER
                      WHEN '' THEN '' 
                      WHEN NULL THEN '' 
                      WHEN SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,12,1) =':' THEN CONCAT( CONCAT( '0', SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,11,1) ), CONCAT(' ', SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,13,2) ) ) 
                      ELSE  CONCAT( CONCAT( '0', SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,11,2) ), CONCAT(' ', SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,13,2) ) ) 
                      END AS "POSTED_MINUTE"
```

Comment: btw, afaik, there is no such thing as `''` (empty string) in Oracle.  It will be treated as a `NULL` I believe. I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: @sstan, you are correct. There is no concept of an empty string in Oracle. Patrick - please could you update your question with some example trans_numbers?

Comment: I didn't realize. I don't know much about the range of values Trans_number might hold - Once I sort this issue out I'll change the first statement to check the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the syntax for [simple and searched CASE statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/case_statement.htm) which is why you're getting the error.

You can rewrite this as:

```
CASE WHEN POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER IS NULL THEN NULL 
     WHEN SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,10,1) = ':' THEN '0'||SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,9,1) 
     ELSE SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,9,2) 
END AS "POSTED_HOUR",
CASE WHEN POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER IS NULL THEN NULL 
     WHEN SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,12,1) =':' THEN '0'||SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,11,1)||' '||SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,13,2)
     ELSE '0'||SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,11,2)||' '||SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,13,2)
END AS "POSTED_MINUTE"
```

N.B. I've replaced each of your `CONCAT()`s with the more common and (IMHO) easily read `||`

Plus the above is untested, since you didn't provide any example data for us to test with.

ETA: You don't even need to explicitly handle the case when POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER is null, as SUBSTR() of a null value returns null.

Comment: This does certainly work, and it's quite easy to read. I had to trim a ) off the SUBSTR in the second line of each.

Comment: *You're mixing CASE statements with CASE expressions.* @Boneist, Technically speaking, it is actually `simple vs searched` case syntax.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Yeah; somewhere I must have gotten myself mixed up, and when I went to link to the documentation, I discovered I was mistaken *{;-)

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg aha, yes; I've updated my answer to remove the extra brackets. See my comment about lack of data to test with *{;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your 3rd when should be nested case:

```
CASE POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER
                  WHEN '' THEN '' 
                  WHEN NULL THEN ''
                   else 
                      case WHEN SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,10,1) =':' THEN CONCAT('0', SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,9,1)) 
                      ELSE SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,9,2) 
                      end 
                  END AS "POSTED_HOUR",
```

Comment: That does indeed work. Can you please tell me why it needed to be nested?

Comment: Because the outer case has the when conditions being compared to "POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER".
The inner case is comparing the value of "SUBSTR(POST_TIME.TRANS_NUMBER,10,1)".

You have 2 different values being compared. Hence, the 2 cases.